# apache karaf clean start

Tags: maven-3, apache-karaf

I'm trying to clean start karaf on Windows using [clean option](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.2.x/users-guide/start-stop.html).
It does delete data directory with bundles cache but it copy new bundles into data directory from system directory not local maven repository. But system directory has stale jars in comparison to local maven repository which cause karaf to start with stale bundles.

Is this a 'feature' of clean option? Am I missing something? How could I start Karaf with latest code from maven repo not dealing with file system?

Answer (score 1):

You can't as the system directory is per default the one to use. 
The clean does mean to clear up bundles in a awkward state and is only rarely used. Sometimes this happens if you start and stop the karaf container very close to each other then bundle might be in an incomplete state and since those bundle state is kept only a clean will help. Another way of cleaning is to delete the data folder. 
So what you look like to be intending is to update certain bundles that are installed from the systems folder. For that you need to install the never version cause Karaf nows which versions are in the systems folder, those bundles are defined in the framework feature which is the basic feature to be used by Karaf itself. 
If you have your own bundles in the system folder there is no way of updating those as those are regarded to be bootfeatures. In case you want to update those you'll need to make sure those features aren't boot features anymore and after that just do install the never versions of your bundles and uninstall the older ones. This can be done with the command shell.

One side note, it's usually best to ask those questions on the users mailinglist of Karaf, you get more people to answer your questions there.